# How do i inject a spring bean into a hibernate SequenceGenerator

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a custom SequenceGenerator written for hibernate:

```
public class LoginGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

    @Autowired
    ITicketService ticketService;

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
        Ticket ticket = (Ticket) obj;
        Long maxCounterOfSection = ticketService.findMaxSectionCounter(ticket
            .getSection());
        maxCounterOfSection++;
        return ticket.getSection() + "-" + maxCounterOfSection;
    }
}
```

But i dont have a spring context inside this generator! ticketService is null. i already tried @Component annotation for my generator, but without success.

PS: Im using spring 3.2.0-FINAL and hibernate 3.6.10-FINAL and there is no way updating to hibernate4!

Any idea, anyone?

Comment: where is this application running? how do you create your spring context?

Comment: Application is running inside Tomcat as a webapp. But that doesnt matter as i also get inside junit test running with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and @ContextConfiguration an error.

Comment: The generator is not instantiated by Spring, so you can't inject anything into it. Hibernate isn't based on Spring.

Comment: I know that hibernate and spring are two different frameworks. I just guessed, if there is any way to springify that class. What do you think of an ApplicationContextAware class holding a static field of the current ApplicationContext, to get the bean by type and/or by name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved with ApplicationContextAware class, as described above.

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(requiredType);
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(name, requiredType);
    }
}
```

In `applicationContext.xml` I added `<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="de.gfz.rz.spring.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>`.

And here the usage:

```
public class LoginGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
        ITicketService ticketService = ApplicationContextProvider
            .getBean(ITicketService.class);
        Ticket ticket = (Ticket) obj;
        Long maxCounterOfSection = ticketService.findMaxSectionCounter(ticket
            .getSection());
        maxCounterOfSection++;
        return ticket.getSection() + "-" + maxCounterOfSection;
    }
}
```